# UINavigationBar disappears on swipe up, but doesn't return on swipe down

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tableView which is embedded in a UINavigation Controller.  In the Nav Controller i've set Hide Bars on Swipe to true (checked).

My tableView performs as expected. Swiping up hides the Nav Bar, Swiping Down makes it visible again.

The issue is when I when I click on a UITableViewCell and Segue (Push) to my detail controller, the Nav Bar hides on when I swipe up, but does not return when I swipe down.

I'd post code, but I've configured all of this in Story Board.

Answer (score 0):

I change my top layout constraint to view rather than layout guide and the problem has resolved itself.